# How to query a many-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am aware that this question was asked several times already, but none of the results were helpful.

I have a many-to-many relationship between tables tracks and genres, that looks like this:

```py
track_genres = Table('track_genres',
                     Base.metadata,
                     Column('tracks_id', INTEGER, ForeignKey('tracks.id'), primary_key=True),
                     Column('genres_id', INTEGER, ForeignKey('genres.id'), primary_key=True)
                     )

class Genre(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'genres'
    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(TEXT)


class Track(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tracks'
    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(TEXT)
    album_id = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey('albums.id'))
    genres = orm.relationship('Genre', secondary=track_genres, backref=orm.backref('tracks', lazy='dynamic',cascade='all'))
```

As far as I am aware, the relationships are declared correctly, since I have following relationships in the track_genres table:

```
tracks_id | genres_id
---------------------
1         | 1        
1         | 2        
1         | 3        
1         | 4        
2         | 1        
2         | 2        
2         | 3        
2         | 4        
3         | 5        
3         | 6        
3         | 7
```

Now, the problem is, when I execute my current query

```py
    query = session.query(
        Track,
        Genre.name.label('genre_name')
    ).filter(
        Track.genres.any(id=Genre.id)
    )
```

I get a result that included all permutations of data, so the track with the ID 1 is being returned by the query 7 times (once with every genre id from 1 to 7), even though it should only be returned only 4 times (since there are only 4 relationships for the track with the ID 1: 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4)

How do I need to write my filter/join in the query so the query returns only the correct results (in this case, for track with the ID = 1, four rows) instead of doing all possible permutations?

Answer (score 0):

After further experimentation I believe the correct approach is to join the respective relationships from tracks:

```py
    query = session.query(
        Track,
        Genre.name.label('genre_name')
    ).join.(
        Track.genres
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you can try *filter* your query by using `contains()` with it.

```
db.session.query(Track).filter(
    Track.genres.contains(genre_obj), 
    Track.genres.contains(genre_obj2),
    # And so on...
)
```